# How can I get Sitecore Field Renderer to use a css class for an image

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

Using Sitecore (7) & MVC, I'd like to know how to add a css class attribute for an image to the field renderer in sitecore.

Without Sitecore it looks like this:

```
<div class="background-container">
   <img src="/images/background-1.jpg" class="background">
</div>
```

With Sitecore:

```
<div class="background-container">
   @Html.Sitecore().Field(Constants.Fields.HomeBackgroundImage)
</div>
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to add the class background to the image itself in Sitecore. Is there another way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sitecore Field Renderer - add markup inside rendering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635647/sitecore-field-renderer-add-markup-inside-rendering)

Comment: Yes, @CBroe I looked at that-not what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was what I was looking for:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("MyFieldName", myItem, new { Parameters = new SafeDictionary<string> { { "enclosing-tag", "h2" } } })
```

See [Extending the Sitecore RenderField pipeline](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorebetter/posts/extending-the-sitecore-renderfield-pipeline).